# C++ - Using Bitmask to get values from an int

Tags: c++, binary, integer, bit-shift, bitmask

I'm given a 32 bit number rendered as an int in the original file. I need the rightmost 8 bits (0-7) in one value and I need the next rightmost 8 bits (8-15) in another. I was told to use bit-masking and bit-shifting to sort that all out but I don't know how it works with integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get only the 8 rightmost bits, you can do

```
int right8 = mynum & 0xFF;
```

Because you are anding the top 24 bits with 0, these will be set to 0, while the bottom 8 will retain their values as they will be anded with ones.

In order to get the next 8 rightmost, you will need to set bits 8-15 to one and all the other to zero in your bitmask. This will maintain the same bits in positions 8-15, but since you need them to be in the bottom 8 bits, you can simply bit shift them 8 positions to the right.  You can do that with the following.

```
int next8 = myNum & 0xFF00;
int next8 = next8 >> 8;
```

Comment: Recommend an edit to beat home exactly what is the shift and what is the mask. It will make the answer a bit more versatile for future askers with a similar, but not exact, problem.

Comment: Alternatively, you can shift right first, then mask the result with 0xFF: `int next8 = (myNum >> 8) & 0xFF;`